# How can I tether my jailbroken iphone to my Ubuntu laptop via USB?

Tags: ubuntu, iphone, usb, tethering

I have a jailbroken iphone that I would like to tether to my Ubuntu computer via USB. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY found it: [PdaNet tethering w/iPhone and Ubuntu Working!](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1351548)

Tried it and it works great (YES)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](http://osxgoodies.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/simple-iphone-3-x-tethering/).

It is mainly dedicated to osx, however should be very similar for ubuntu.